# VBA Vlookup from a saved file

Tags: excel, vba

I have a dynamic report extracted from SAP, that I need to run a Vlookup Formula in it from a closed file on my PC.

so what I basically do is VBA to open the source file that I will vlookup from then run the Vlookup formula in my sap extracted workbook.

My problem is how to let the formula run on the Sheet extracted from SAP, The VBA code is in personal file, not the extracted SAP sheet so I can't use thisworkbook function.

```
    Sub Vllokp()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim wb1 As Workbook
 Workbooks.Open "C:\User\1.Work\18.SAP GUI and Automation\Payment propsal Test\Bank.xlsx"
Set wb = Workbooks("Bank.xlsx")
Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1")

 
 
With wb1.Sheets("sheet1")
       .Range("AA2").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(D1,'[Bank.xlsx]Sheet1'!A:C,3,FALSE)"
    
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me,

```
Sub Vllokp()
Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook
 
 
 Workbooks.Open "C:\User\1.Work\18.SAP GUI and Automation\Payment propsal Test\Bank.xlsx"
Set wb = Workbooks("Bank.xlsx")


  
With wb1.Sheets("sheet1")
       .Range("AA2").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(D1,'[Bank.xlsx]Sheet1'!A:C,3,FALSE)"
    .Range("AA2").copy Range("AA3:AA" & Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row - 1)
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).